# General rules for functional derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculus-of-variations

As the existing googled posts about functional derivatives are very complicated with a lot of math symbols, I am looking for if there exists a summary table of the general rules of functional derivatives that are easier to apply.

The example below from [Matlab's functionalDerivative(f,[u,v])](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.functionalderivative.html) illustrates my perplexity:

$\displaystyle S[ u,\ v] \ =\int _{b}^{a}\left( u^{2}( x)\frac{dv( x)}{dx} +v( x)\frac{d^{2} u( x)}{dx^{2}}\right) dx$

where the integrand is $\displaystyle f[ u( x) ,\ v( x) ,\ u''( x) ,\ v'( x)] \ =u^{2}\frac{dv}{dx} +v\frac{d^{2} u}{dx^{2}} \ $.

We want to find the functional derivative of the functional $\displaystyle S[ u,\ v] \ $ with respect to the two functions $\displaystyle u( x)$ and $\displaystyle v( x)$.

As far as I understand, the rule of functional derivative is similar to the ordinary derivative of a function as long as I consider the integrand as an ordinary function and see $\displaystyle u( x)$ and $\displaystyle v( x)$ as ordinary single variables of the function. So the derivative of $\displaystyle u^{2}\frac{dv}{dx}$ w.r.t $\displaystyle u$ will be $\displaystyle 2u\frac{dv}{dx}$  , which is the familiar product rule in ordinary derivatives.

My questions:

1. Are there easy rules to obtain the derivative of $\displaystyle v\frac{d^{2} u}{dx^{2}}$ w.r.t $\displaystyle u$?
2. Similarly, how about the derivative of $\displaystyle u^{2}\frac{dv}{dx}$ w.r.t $\displaystyle v$?

The derivatives of the functional $\displaystyle S[ u,\ v] \ $ w.r.t $\displaystyle u$ and $\displaystyle v$ provided by Matlab are
$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
\begin{pmatrix}
2u( x)\frac{d}{dx} v( x) +\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}} v( x)\\
-2u( x)\frac{d}{dx} u( x) +\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}} u( x)
\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{array}$.

Comment: may get better answers on math SE

Comment: The derivative of $u^2dv/dx$ with respect to $u$ is not $2udv/dx$. Look up Frechet derivative and Gateaux derivative. For actual computation of the Frechet derivative, the Gateux derivative is often a good method.

Comment: @Mason I infer that from the solution from Matlab. Isn't it the correct way? I will much appreciate it if you could give me a hand with the solution in detail.

Comment: There is no "functional derivative" just the maps $w\mapsto \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{S[u+hw,v]-S[u,v]}h$ and $z\mapsto \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{S[u,v+hz]-S[u,v]}h$ sending functions to real numbers and computed in the usual way (derivative of $S[u+hw,v]$ wrt $h$ at $h=0$)

Comment: @user7283235 Gateux derivative of a map $F : V \to W$ betqeen normed spaces $V, W$ in the direction of a vector $\phi$ is $D_{\phi}F(v) = \frac{d}{dt}f(v + t\phi)|_{t = 0}$. So $D_{\phi}F : V \to W$. Now take $F$ to be your functional. To derive the functional derivative, take $\phi$ to be a test function, as stated in the MATLAB documentation you linked.